# Why is my file doesn't read to a zip archive

Tags: java, file-io, zip

I have a code snippet, that in theory should read a path to an archive first, when write a file to the archive. (But that thing takes zip and for instance some txt file, and really move it to zip, but the file is empty) First, i thought this thing doesn't work since i didn't close streams, but now i use try-with, so the problem should be gone, but it is not.

```
 public void createZip(Path source) throws Exception
    {
        try(ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(source));
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(zipFile)))
        {
            ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(source.getFileName().toString());
            zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

            int data;

            while((data = zipIn.read()) > 0)
            {
                zipOut.write(data);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To use correctly the ZipOutputStream after adding the entry you need to flush the zip.
Try adding the following at the endo of your method:

```
zipOut.flush();
```

Comment: No, there's still nothing and the size of the file in the zip is 0

Comment: You also don't get the first entry of the zip, before reading from the original archive add `zipIn.getNextEntry();`  this will move your cursor to the first file of the source archive.